# Dirichlet divisor problem with multiple factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $D(x)$ denote the number of pairs of natural numbers $(j,k)$ such that $j k\leq x$. It is well known that $D(x) =x \log x + (2 \gamma-1) x + $lower order terms in the large $x$ limit (Dirichlet divisor problem).

What happens if three factors are used? viz.

Let $D_3(x)$ denote the number of triplets of natural numbers $(j,k,\ell)$ such that $j k \ell \leq x$. What is the limiting form of $D_3(x)$? Has this problem been studied?

Comment: @Tony, this site supports LaTeX output, just place it between dollar signs.  Also, be careful with extra spaces at the beginning of lines - Markdwon may interpret it as something different: http://mathoverflow.net/editing-help

Answer (score 9):

This problem is classical and important, for example in the elementary proof of the prime number theorem that goes back to Selberg.

In general, if $D_k(x)$ denotes the number of positive integral tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ such that $x_1\dots x_k\leq x$, then by a variant of Dirichlet's hyperbola method it follows that

$$ D_k(x) = x P_k(\log x) + O_k(x^{1-1/k}), $$

where $P_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with real coefficients. The error term can be improved by deeper methods (e.g. Vinogradov).

Actually the above statement is Exercise 2 on Page 22 of Iwaniec-Kowalski: Analytic number theory.

Comment: To add to GH's answer: In his book on the zeta-function, I believe Titchmarsh calls the problem of finding the best possible error term for $D_k(x)$, when $k>2$ is an integer, the "Piltz Divisor Problem."

Comment: Okay guys thanks for that! It looks like the leading term in $P_k(x)$ is $x^{k-1}/(k-1)!$ based on Ivic's book on Riemann zeta function (he gives the first three polynomials explicitly). Is this correct? I'm using it for an eigenvalue calculation and only need the leading term.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In fact $xP_k(\log x)$ is the residue at $s=1$ of $\zeta^k(s)x^s/s$.